# How to select the contents of a textbox once it is activated?

Tags: excel, vba, events, textbox

I have this simple Userform, where I only have `TextBox1` and `TextBox2`. I enter some text in both of them. Assume the focus is on (the cursor is in) the `TextBox2`. When I click on `TextBox1`, I want the whole text in this control to be highlighted (selected). Thus I use this code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    With TextBox1
        .SetFocus
        .SelStart = 0
        .SelLength = Len(.Text)
    End With
    MsgBox "enter event was fired"
End Sub
```

There is a `MsgBox` at the end which is loaded, that means the event works. However, the text is not highlighted. How to fix this?

I use the `Enter` event and don't want to use the `MouseDown` event, because I need the code to also work when the `TextBox1` is activated programatically, so I feel the `Enter` event to be the best choice, as it's fired in both cases! Another drawback of the `MouseDown` event is: when I click for the second time on the `TextBox1`, I would not expect the whole text to be highlighted anymore, because the focus was set on the first click and it was not changed after I clicked on the same control for the second time; so in this case I would like the cursor to act normally (not to keep the text marked).

**Update**

When I click once on the `TextBox1`, I expect to have this result:
[image]

If clicked again, the highlight would be removed and the cursor would be placed in the place where it was clicked.

Comment: I didn't manage to reproduce your problem as your code was already working for me, even when used programatically!

Comment: You already have a property for this named `EnterFieldBehavior`. You just need to set it to `fmEnterFieldBehaviorSelectAll`. This is the default value for this property, so you don't need to do anything unless you have changed the property value. It should work without any bit of code.

Comment: @R3uK I don't know why, but having the above code alone does not work for me - the text is not selected on click. As [@vacip](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4713729/vacip) said, the reason might be that the actual (hidden) *click* event happens after Enter event and that simply cancels the selection.

Comment: @PradeepKumar I saw that property and tried both available options. No use. I kind of think that this property is bugged, because it should do exactly what I need and it doesn't. Have you tested this behaviour? If that's working, could you please share a screenshot's containing all the properties of the textbox, so that I could try it with the same set up?

Comment: My bad.. I should have read the documentation properly before commenting here. It states that that property is only for Tab keypress and not for anything else. Its here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251742.aspx

Comment: I proposed a simple [solution below with little code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63858576/9150270) to "consider" the TextBox/ComboBox property `EnterFieldBehavior` so that the value `fmEnterFieldBehaviorSelectAll` (if chosen) is applied when the user form is displayed and the initial focus is on that field.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Can't be more simple than this I guess...

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    With TextBox1
        .SelStart = 0
        .SelLength = Len(.Text)
    End With
End Sub
```

Whether you click on the textbox or you tab into it, it will do what you want. To deselect the text, use the arrow keys.

**Explanation**

If you debug the code you will see that even though you have said `.SetFocus`, the focus is not on the Textbox. `.SetFocus` doesn't work in `TextBox1_Enter()` and you need to have focus for the rest of the code to work. And hence my alternative...

**Alternative**

You may also like this version :) This overcomes the limitation of using the mouse in the TextBox

```
Dim boolEnter As Boolean

Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    boolEnter = True
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If boolEnter = True Then
        With TextBox1
            .SelStart = 0
            .SelLength = Len(.Text)
        End With
        boolEnter = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems that the alternative option works brilliantly! I tried to do a very similar thing with variables on a module level, but without success. Thanks for shedding light! Now I'll just leave it like that in my application just to ensure it works in every case.

Comment: @Siddharth nice, +1 :-).

Comment: Huge thanks! P.S.: A coincidence - just recently I started working with VB.NET (really difficult at the moment) and I happened to land on [your blog](https://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/vb-net-and-excel/) which is a huge help :) You're awesome! :)

Comment: @ZygD: Please do not visit that link :) I don't update that anymore. [Here](http://www.siddharthrout.com/) is the link you may want to visit.

Comment: But there's [nothing within](http://www.siddharthrout.com/vb-dot-net-and-excel/)? Empty page loads.

Comment: Strange, you are the second person who has told me that. Go to this site https://zend2.com/ and then surf to my webpage from there.Can you see it now? If yes then seems like your country is blocking my IP... Strange

Comment: Yes, now it works. I think it would be a good idea to put this info into your old blog. I'm from Lithuania (EU), btw. You're the first person to show me that something is blocked for me. I'm not so sure if it's on country level, or ISP. However, I think I'd go for country level... :( I will discuss this with my ISP. And now the first link works!

Comment: awesome. No idea what happened :)

Answer (score 5):

Pff, took me a while. Actually, your code works, but it highlights the text BEFORE the click event happens. So you clicking in the box instantly overrides the selection created by the code.
I have used a delayed selection, and it works, though it is a bit disgusting...

The code for the textboxes:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
  Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "module1.SelectText1"
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Enter()
  Application.OnTime Now, "module1.SelectText2"
End Sub
```

Note that it works even withouth the {+ TimeValue("00:00:01")} part, but it might theoretically stop it from working at times. Hmm, on a second thought, just leave it out. I doubt it would ever cause a problem.

Now the code in module1:

```
Sub SelectText1()
  UserForm1.TextBox1.SelStart = 0
  UserForm1.TextBox1.SelLength = Len(UserForm1.TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Sub SelectText2()
  UserForm1.TextBox2.SelStart = 0
  UserForm1.TextBox2.SelLength = Len(UserForm1.TextBox2.Text)
End Sub
```

Hope this works for you too. Ineresting problem. :) Cheers!

Comment: Very thanks for the answer. It works. Really nice use of `Application.OnTime`, and very thanks for clarifying that the actual *click* happens before the text is highlighted by my code. The code works, however, I'll wait for several days, maybe someone else could provide another solution (as you said, this does not look very beautiful, although I really like it).

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't manage to select/highlight text in the Enter event as the the mousedown and mouseup events coming after are somewhat resetting the selection.

I think the most proper way of achieving what you want is this :

```
' if you want to allow highlight more then once, reset the  variable LastEntered prior to call SelectTboxText:
'       LastEntered = ""
'       SelectTboxText TextBox2


Dim LastEntered As String


' Button to select Textbox1
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    SelectTboxText TextBox1
End Sub

' Button to select Textbox2
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    SelectTboxText TextBox2
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    SelectTboxText TextBox1
End Sub


Private Sub TextBox2_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
     SelectTboxText TextBox2
End Sub


Public Sub SelectTboxText(ByRef tBox As MSForms.TextBox)

    If LastEntered <> tBox.Name Then

        LastEntered = tBox.Name

        With tBox
            .SetFocus
            .SelStart = 0
            .SelLength = Len(.Text)
        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

So each time you want to activate one of the textbox programmatically, you should call the sub SelectTboxText, which is not really annoying IMO. I made 2 buttons for this as an example.

Comment: Nice solution. Though this makes cursor placement by mouse impossible, as it always selects the whole contents of the textbox whenever you click inside it. ZygD said: "If clicked again, the highlight would be removed and the cursor would be placed in the place where it was clicked."

Comment: Have you tested it ? because according to me It does what was required and not what you think it will do. The check on variable `LastEntered` is there for that, it only highlight the text on FIRST mouse event of the same textbox

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I have totally skipped the last entered part. It does work now.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. However, for now, I've implemented the solution proposed by [Siddharth Rout](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout). I've made what you said - separated the process to another sub in order to do stuff programmatically. I also found useful `msforms.textbox`, because previously I called that thing just a `control`, which is not that accurate :)

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat an enhancement of what @vacip posted. The benefit you get is that you don't need to add a separate method in the Module for each new textbox.

The following code in your User Form:

```
'===== User Form Code ========

Option Explicit

Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    OnTextBoxEnter
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Enter()
   OnTextBoxEnter
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_Enter()
   OnTextBoxEnter
End Sub
```

The following code goes in a Module:

```
'===== Module Code ========

Sub SelectAllText()
    SendKeys "{HOME}+{END}", True
End Sub

Sub OnTextBoxEnter()
   Application.OnTime Now + 0.00001, "SelectAllText", Now + 0.00002
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you just explain how much time is added with `+ 0.00001` statement? Is it in seconds, minutes or hours?

Comment: It adds 1 second and is functionally same as `TimeValue("00:00:01")`. The `OnTextBoxEnter` function causes it to execute the `SelectAllText` after 1 second and wait for another 1 second before it cancels the operation, in case it doesn't get executed for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()                                                                
    TextBox1.SetFocus
    TextBox1.SelStart = 0
    TextBox1.SelLength = Len(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Add this to the form's code

Answer (score 0):

I know this is well out of date but I'm leaving this here in case it helps someone in my position.

What I want is:

- **If I click on the box for the first time: select all the text**
- **If I click on it a subsequent time: put the cursor where the mouse is and allow me to use the mouse to select a substring**

Firstly it is important to know that "Select all the text" is the default behaviour when tabbing into a TextBox and that "Put the cursor here" is the default behaviour when clicking on a TextBox so we only need to worry about what the mouse is doing.

To do this, we can keep track of the Active Control, but only while the mouse is moving over our TextBox (ie. before the Click)

**Code**:

```
Private m_ActiveControlName As String

Private Sub Text1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    m_ActiveControlName = Me.ActiveControl.Name
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If m_ActiveControlName <> Me.Text1.Name Then
        Call Text1_Enter   'we don't have to use Text1_Enter for this, any method will do
        Exit Sub           'quit here so that VBA doesn't finish doing its default Click behaviour
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_Enter()
    With Text1
        .SelStart = 0
        .SelLength = Len(.Text)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another solution than the one given by Siddharth.

EDIT: **but** there's this [bug of `SendKeys`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018232/send-keys-is-disabling-numlock), so the solution I propose below is a lot worse than Siddharth one. I keep it in case one day the bug is corrected...

It relies on the property `EnterFieldBehavior` of the TextBox field. This property works only when the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is pressed to enter that field, and if this property is `fmEnterFieldBehaviorSelectAll` (0) the whole field text is automatically selected.

So a dummy caret movement between fields when the form is shown, will activate the feature automatically. For instance this movement can be achieved by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move to the next field, and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move to the previous field (so back to the original field):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    SendKeys "{TAB}+{TAB}"
End Sub
```

The (very little) advantage of this solution is that you can tune your user form by editing manually the properties `EnterFieldBehavior`, `TabIndex`, `TabKeyBehavior` and `TabStop` without changing the VBA code anymore to set "select all" on the field with the initial focus.

In short, the VBA code above tells to consider the property `EnterFieldBehavior` of the field which has the initial focus when the user form is displayed (provided that it's a TextBox or ComboBox field of course).

Answer (score -2):

use this

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    With TextBox2
        .ForeColor = vbBlack
        .Font.Bold = False
    End With
    With TextBox1
        .ForeColor = vbRed
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Enter()
    With TextBox1
        .ForeColor = vbBlack
        .Font.Bold = False
    End With
    With TextBox2
        .ForeColor = vbRed
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Vasily. I'm afraid I was not clear enough. I updated the question with a screenshot of the *"highlight"* that I want to achieve.

Answer (score -2):

The behavior you're trying to implement is already built in to the `TextBox`. When you move the mouse over the left side of the text box, the mouse pointer will point to the right. If you click, it will select all the text in the field. Clicking anywhere else will deselect the text.

I will try a few other strategies to see if I can get this to work in one Sub.

Comment: That should be a comment and not a solution. This doesn't solve anything

Comment: Thanks, Kris, for the comment. This built-in usage is not very convenient, this is why I look for another, more intuitive solution.

Answer (score -2):

Try the same code with `TextBox1_MouseDown`. It should work.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    With TextBox1
        .SetFocus
        .SelStart = 0
        .SelLength = Len(.Text)
    End With
    MsgBox "Text in TextBox1 is selected"
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but as I said in the question, `MouseDown` alone does not help me, because I also want to be able to easily call the function programmatically. So far, the problem seems to be solved, as I have implemented [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117252/how-to-select-the-contents-of-a-textbox-once-it-is-activated#30178650) provided by [Siddharth Rout](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout) after moving his code provided in `MouseDown` to a separate function.