# vba Excel - Select only the last character in a textbox

Tags: vba

I have a form where I enter orders into. One of the fields is an order number textbox. Now as many know, order numbers can be very long, and they mostly follow numerically (The once I read in do - mostly). So I want to tab to the orders textbox, and have it highlight only the last number (the previous order number that I entered is still in the textbox) so that if the number was `5467245`, then it will only highlight the number `5` and I would only have to press `6` in order to change the number to `4567246`

PS: I thought about just adding +1 to the order number automatically, but sometimes they skip a number and then I would have to press `7` instead of `6` keeping with the above example.

What I have at the moment based from this answer: [Highlight all text in textbox once it is activated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117252/how-to-select-the-contents-of-a-textbox-once-it-is-activated)

```
Private Sub txb_orderNumber_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
        With txb_orderNumber
        .SetFocus
        If Len(.Text) > 0 Then
            .SelStart = Len(.Text) - 1
            .SelLength = 1
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```

But it only works when I click into the textbox with the mouse (So it actually works, but only with the mouse click), **even though** the author says that it will work when I tab into the textbox - but it doesn't work when I tab into it (This may be because I do not want to highlight the whole value, as in his example). And I really need it to work with the tab key.

So that is the question - how can I make it work when I tab into the textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your code works in the `Enter` event with the controls `EnterFieldBehavior` property set to `1 - fmEnterFieldBehaviorRecallSelection`.

```
Private Sub txtb_orderNumber_Enter()
    With Me.txtb_orderNumber
        If Len(.Text) > 0 Then
            .SelStart = Len(.Text) - 1
            .SelLength = 1
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Darren Much cleaner and better solution! I tried `_Enter` but then that post said that it wouldn't work with `.setFocus`. So thanks for this, worked great!