# Select/highlight all text in textbox when clicking in it

Tags: vba, excel

I think this one is simple, but i can't figure out how to make it work.

My form has a textbox. When the user clicks in the textbox i want the macro to select all the text.
With this code nothing happens when clicking in the textbox:

```
Private Sub TextBox_Enter()
    With TextBox
        .SetFocus
        .SelStart = 0
        .SelLength = Len(TextBox)
    End With
End Sub
```

I think the problem is, that the 'enter' event fires even before the textbox is focused. Which event should i select? There's nothing like 'OnEnter' or 'GotFocus'.

Has someone a solution for highliting all the text when clicking in the textbox?

I appreciate any help

Comment: Great answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117252/how-to-select-the-contents-of-a-textbox-once-it-is-activated) SO article.

Comment: If you want to trap a click the it's the click event. `Event Click()
    Member of VB.TextBox
    Occurs when the user presses and then releases a mouse button over an object.
` from Object  Browser (F2 in the VBA editor).